# Windows 10 installer keeps asking for a media driver

Tags: hard-drive, drivers, ssd

A few days ago my hard drive got erased.
I'm trying to install Windows 10 on it, but it keeps asking for a driver.
I've tried searching online and I really can't find it.

My hard drive is a SK hynix BC551.

My hard drive is an M.2 NVMe SSD if that helps.

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I can provide some more information. The disk's data is completely gone, but the disk itself seems to be completely fine. I was able to format it with NTFS, write a .txt file to a partition, and read the .txt file using the Command Prompt and Notepad during stage 1 of the install, even after a restart. I do agree that it may have encountered some sort of failure and destroyed something important for Windows to boot. I'll try to provide more info next time I ask here. The installer was also actually asking for the storage controller's driver, I must have misremembered it as the hard disk driver. The actual message said something a media driver for a storage controller.
Really sorry for being so vague with the original.

Comment: _"it keeps asking for a driver"_ - the installer? Are you sure it's asking for a driver for the hard drive specifically? And not for the storage controller driver?

Comment: ^^this is the thing. @OP search windows website for "SSD controller", or your unspecified PC manufacturer's website for same. !Jeez windows. A 35GB install and you can't include even generic drivers! Also how does one's HDD "get erased"??

Comment: "It keeps asking for a driver." - This happens when you boot the installation environment in UEFI mode but only have an MBR disk connected.  It also happens when you boot the installation environment in Legacy mode and only have the GPT disk connected.  Windows 10+ does not require any special drives to install to an SSD.  To rule out this possibility, does this drive have any partitions?

Comment: If it does, you should delete all of them and make sure you boot the installation media with UEFI mode, and Secure Boot enabled.  If it has no partitions, or you cannot confirm if it does or doesn't, then in all likelihood, the drive has failed.  At this point, you have not provided enough information to answer your question.  Additionally, "The installer was also actually asking for the storage controller's driver", I can tell you with an absolute certainty this did not happen.  The storage controller is natively supported by the installation environment.

Answer (score 0):

"my hard drive got erased" is very vague, but I assume that your SSD has
encountered a catastrophic error that caused a total failure.

In general, the SK hynix SSDs do not require a driver in Windows.
The [download page](https://ssd.skhynix.com/download/)
does not contain drivers, having only firmware downloads
(which is the software inside the disk, not in Windows).

If Windows finds the disk to be unusable, this means that it has failed.
I suggest it is time to replace it.

Comment: >If Windows finds the disk to be unusable, this means that it has failed.
This is patently untrue. Windows, afaik, still identifies any non-MS file system as "empty" or "unformatted" Despite the disk being completely functional with every other OS.

Comment: @mitts: My answer was written under the impression that this disk was already used on Windows but now has failed. But as it turned out, the disk is fine and the error message was just misleading.